# Using Jquery UI with express.js

Tags: node.js, jquery-ui, backbone.js, express, pug

I am working with a node-backbone application. I create dynamic content and add jquery UI draggable to the content or elements I create. However, when my template system renders, my elements will not even move. The paths are correct. I use a class to make a reference to those elements and the draggable method.

Can someone tell me what is the correct way to include the jquery ui and jquery scripts so they load correctly?

layout jade - index.jade - template (extend layout) rendered in the index.jade

In my app I have a jquery module which is connected to backbone, but for some reason the jquery UI does not connect with it and consequently I have to add a jquery script next it. But then the jquery will not work when I create the dynamic elements with backbone into my templates. I use .html() to add them to template.

This is layout.jade

```
!!! 5
html(lang="en")
  head
    title project
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
    link(rel='stylesheet',href='/styles/bootstrap.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet',href='/styles/styles.css')

  body
   .navbar.navbar-inverse
    .container
        button.navbar-toggle(type='button', data-toggle='collapse', data-target='.nav-collapse')
          span.icon-bar
          span.icon-bar
          span.icon-bar
        a.navbar-brand(href='#') 
         img(src='/img/greatlogowhite.png', width='300')
        .nav-collapse.collapse
          ul.nav.navbar-nav
            li.active
             a(href='#') 
              img(src='/img/house.svg', width='70')
            li
             a(href='#about')
              img(src='/img/pen.svg', width='70')
            li
             a(href='#contact')
              img(src='/img/search.svg', width='70')
            li
             a(href='#contact')
              img(src='/img/chat.svg', width='70')
```

This is index.jade

```
  block content
  block scripts


extends layout

block content
  div#content

block scripts
  script(data-main='js/boot', type='text/javascript',src='/js/libs/require.js')
  script(type='text/javascript', src='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js')
```

This is how I try to use jquery ui

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
           $( ".pic" ).draggable();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Show us how you're loading jquery and jquery ui

Comment: show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I made it to solve the problem. Whoever uses backbone, node.js, and require.js, remember to include jquery and jquery UI as libraries with require, and when creating dynamic elements with backbone such as:

```
$('#content').append(html); inside backbone call jquery UI

            $('.drag').draggable();
```